# @Override Error: method does not override method from superclass (Android Studio)

Tags: java, android-studio, overriding

After creating any new android project inside android studio, the following error happens:
[image: Screenshot]

It's an error related to `@Override`, saying:

> method does not override method from superclass

How would I resolve this error?

Comment: Look at your list of imports to see if you are importing "AppCompatActivity". If not, right click on the red `AppCompatActivity` and select "import". If you are already importing it, wait for the Gradle Sync to complete and see if it fixes it. If that doesn't fix it, choose "Invalidate Caches and Restart" from the file menu then do a clean build. The root cause of the override error is that the super class isn't found by the IDE.

Answer (score 0):

When you add @Override to a method, if

> method does not override method from superclass

appears. It means IDE can't find the method with same signature in its super class.

From my view, I guess you didn't add the library which contains `AppCompatActivity` properly. Please have it examined.

Comment: **please tell how to add it.**

Comment: Sorry for the delay.I have no such experience，you'd better find the answer yourself or start another SO question thread